# jQuery $.ajax post getting referer url for error debugging

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

i want to create a function for sending error messages from $.ajax posts via email to myself, here's my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my_url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(request, settings) {
            request.settings = settings;
        },
        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function (request, status, error)
        {
            send_error(status, error, request);
        }
    });
```

i mapped the request.settings into the ajax call in order to receive extra infos for my send_error function. i'm getting infos like url, type, data, responseText (= server's error message).
i would like also getting the referrer URL so i can see where it was triggered.
seems it's only inside the responseText, a link inside the server's error message. 
is there a better alternative for getting the referrer URL?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to get the referer, however the variable I'm using is unreliable and can be spoofed but then again, everything in Javascript can be spoofed too.

```
error: function (request, status, error){
    send_error(status, error, request, "<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>");
}
```

An alternative to this is to track the user over your website using sessions.
Append each `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in a `$_SESSION['referer']` array and print the second last index directly to Javascript.

Comment: thanks i know this function but i actually wanted to get the referrer url only